# stickit doesn't save values from autocomplete fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, autocomplete, backbone-stickit

I have plugged autocomplete after in initialize function as advised from stickit documentation.

Almost hello world world example:

```
MyApp.Views.Form = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#my-form",
    bindings: {
        "#postcode_with_suburbs": {
            observe: "postcode",
            initialize: function($el, model, options) {
                $el.autocomplete({
                    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ] 
                })
            },
            onSet: function(val, options) {
                return $("#postcode_with_suburbs").val(); 
            }
        },
    },
    events: {
        "click #form-submit" : "submit",
    },
    initialize : function() {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change");
            this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(JST['backbone/templates/car_insurance/form']);
            this.stickit();
        return this;
    }
});
```

So the problem is whenever a user fills the form and autocomletes the postcode by **clicking** the autocomplete value it is not saved to the model attribute. `Saved as ja` instead of `java`

[image]

However scrolling down with a keyboard over the options from an autocomplete, the values is set properly to the attribute of a model. `Saved as java`

Comment: Difficult to respond with these elements. We don't see the html markup. Could you provide a jsfiddle that reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The stickit bindings does bind an event listener for `change input keyup` events on bound DOM element of type `<input>`. Uses the listener to update the model attribute. The element `postcode_with_suburbs`, in your case, being an *input* type should fire `change` event when user selects one of the option from drop down. I don't know why it is not firing the event. Try this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykjs121/76egD/) See the changes

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).trigger("change", event);
}
```

In `select` event callback of autocomplete, I'm triggering change event explicitly on the element. You can also configure `events: [autocompleteselect]` instead of `select` callback.